# touchmove and mousemove use same function, how to clean my code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function crosshair(circle_cursor) {
  circle_cursor.on({
    'touchstart touchmove': function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var orig = e.originalEvent;
      var x4 = orig.changedTouches[0].pageX;
      var y4 = orig.changedTouches[0].pageY;

      cH.css('top', y4);
      cV.css('left', x4);
      coordinates( x4, y4 );

      alertMsg.css({
        display: 'block',
        top: y4 - map.offset().top + 30,
        left: x4 - map.offset().left - 80
      });
    },

    'mousemove': function(e){
      var clientX = e.pageX,
          clientY = e.pageY,
          target_position = point.offset(),
          x1 = target_position.left,
          y1 = target_position.top,
          d = distance(clientX, clientY, x1, y1);

      goPoint.hide();
      hair.show();

      cH.css('top', clientY + 25);
      cV.css('left', clientX + 24);

      //Display coordinates
      coordinates(clientX, clientY);

      //Display message box
      alertMsg.css({
        display: 'block',
        top: clientY - map.offset().top + 60,
        left: clientX - map.offset().left - 90
      });
    }
   });
```

This is part of my code, basically I'm using the same functions for touchstart and mousemove. However, the method used to detect the coordinates are different.

How can I combine these?

Thanks!

Comment: still learning it, but not good enough yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should separate detection of directions (event.changedTouches[0].pageX, event.pageX) and moving of the object within the page.

E.g. making a generic function which handles the moving:

```
function move(x, y) {}
```

and keep the event handler but without page interaction logic. Only detecting input positions and give them to the `move(x, y)` function.